# Accessing new state in current handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a handler that changes some state of my react application, let's say it shuffles state entry `data`:

```
state = {
   data:[1,2,3,4,5]
  };

 public handleShuffle = () => {
    const current = this.state.data;
    const shuffled = current
      .map((a: any) => [Math.random(), a])
      .sort((a: any, b: any): any => a[0] - b[0])
      .map((a: any) => a[1]);
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      data: shuffled
    });
    consoleLog(this.state.data[0])
  };
```

Is there a way to access this new shuffled array still in this handler so there is a log of not 1 which is previous state, but a new shuffled one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` accepts a second callback argument when you pass an object as the first:

```
this.setState({ data: shuffled }, () => {
  this.state.data === shuffled // true
}
```

Assuming you're in the same scope, you don't actually need the callback since you already have the value of the soon-to-be state in `shuffled` and you can continue to use it.

Generally if you want to wait until `this.state` is updated and the component has been re-rendered it's recommended that you use `componentDidUpdate` instead of the `setState` callback.

Note that `setState` will already do a shallow diff on the object you pass in and merge in new updates. You don't need to do this: `setState({ ...this.state })`, and doing so is in fact harmful.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass second argument to `setState`.
Please try this:

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  data: shuffled
}, () => console.log(this.state.data[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The state update is async and `setState` has a callback

try this

```
public handleShuffle = () => {
const current = this.state.data;
const that = this;
const shuffled = current
  .map((a: any) => [Math.random(), a])
  .sort((a: any, b: any): any => a[0] - b[0])
  .map((a: any) => a[1]);
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  data: shuffled
}, ()=>{
   consoleLog(that.state.data[0])
});
};
```